# Stochastic integral over an $L^2_\text{loc}$ function is a continuous local martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Let $B_t$ be any standard Brownian motion and let $f \in L^2_\text{loc}$. Then $W = \int_0^{\cdot} f(\cdot,s)\, dB_s$ is a continuous local martingale.

This is stated in my lecture notes right after the definition of 'local martingale' without a proof. I don't know if this is supposed to be trivial or if the proof is omitted as an exercise. Since this seems like a general result can somebody point be in a direction where I can find more information or a proof for this theorem?

Comment: Is $f$ a function of two real variables? $f\in L^2_\text{loc}(\mathbb R^2) \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is not stated any more clearly in my notes. I just assumed that for fixed $s$ we have $f(\cdot ,s) \in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy nevermind, it is stated earlier in the notes that $L^2_{loc}$ is used as an abbreviation for all functions $f: \Omega \times [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}$ that are measurable, adapted and $\int_0^{T} f^2(\cdot,s)\, ds$ is finite.

Comment: I just found what I was looking for [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=VgQDWyihxKYC&pg=PA162&dq=oksendal+stochastic+differential+equations+Corollary3.2.6&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjpPWt6czmAhWPUMAKHeN6AS8Q6AEIMzAB#v=onepage&q=corollary%203.2.6&f=false) . However the proof just sites 3 earlier lemmas/theorems. I can't say I understand how they proof the proposition.. Can somebody help me out?